# Scrapy dynamically adding columns to output in the .csv

Tags: python, logging, dynamic, scrapy

My web scraper is working fine so far, the logic is to scrape the target site and according to the content, it may jump to another site to scrape more information.

In the second site, it may have one or more useful data required to be scraped. So, the bottomline, the .csv sometimes may required to scrape and save more columns.

I made a small code below to check it, it looks like the first all of "yield" defines the amount of columns. You can test it by changing the < to > sign in the comparison below.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Quotes'
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ('http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
                 )

def parse(self, response):
    quotes = response.xpath('//*[@class="quote"]')

    i = 0
    for quote in quotes:

        i = i + 1

        text = quote.xpath('.//*[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
        author = quote.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="author"]/text()').extract_first()
        tags = quote.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="keywords"]/@content').extract_first()

        if i <= 5: # change the < by > and evalute columns in the new log.
            yield{'Text': text,
                  'Author': author,
                  'Tags': tags,
                  'Extra key' : 'dummy!' }               
        else:            
            yield{'Text': text,
                  'Author': author,
                  'Tags': tags}
```

So, how can I add later (if possible) more columns that I don't know in advance when my script started?

Comment: I ran your code, no .csv files so far.

Comment: Use this command to run scrapy scripts:

scrapy crawl Quotes -o result123.csv

Comment: Probably create an Item class and define item fields there, so scrapy will  up front know how many columns to create in CSV